# Touchscreen calibration off for SDL applications?

Tags: xorg, xinput, touch-screen

I have a touchscreen that I've calibrated in X using xinput-calibrator in Debian, but I noticed that some apps still don't seem to respect the calibration values at all. For example, running SCUMMVM in full screen mode results in the touch screen being inverted.

Is there anything I can do about this? I was exploring using tslib, but it doesn't seem to be compatible with the touchscreen I'm using.

Answer (score 1):

When your touchscreen device driver uses the standard Linux input event device system, tslib is compatible. Just use `module_raw input` in your `ts.conf`.

And with version 1.3, instead of using a tslib plugin for X, you can use `tslib/tools/ts_uinput` which again provides a input event device you can just point your environment to. For more details, see [tslib's documentation](https://github.com/kergoth/tslib/blob/master/README.md).